# A new Firebase "ListenerForSingleValueEvent" stops working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm experimenting with Firebase for Android and wrote a login system.
My app allows the user to register and log in with a username.

There are times when neither onDataChange or onCancelled gets called.
I searched for documentation and tried out the goOnline() method on the database
before requesting a value but it doesn't solve the problem

I also checked the connection status and saw that my app is disconnected, how can i connect my app again to firebase to check if the username already exists?

This is not the only singleEventListener that doesn't work after a while, this happens for all of them

When testing the app after the first install, there's no problem. It starts from the second time when i open the app after a while, that the listeners stop working for that session and all app sessions after that

```
//check if username is available

mDatabase.goOnline();
mDatabase.child("usernameToEmail").child(mUsernameView.getText().toString())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    showProgress(false);
                    mUsernameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_username_taken));
                    mUsernameView.requestFocus();
                    showKeyboard();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    register(email,username,password);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
                //do nothing
                showProgress(false);
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        });
```

Comment: The Firebase Database client immediately tries to connect when you first start using it. If it doesn't create a connection, it's likely because your device is not connected to the network or because there is something between your device and the Firebase servers that blocks the traffic.

Comment: Really weird, i have internet connection on my device. Btw: the first time my app launches after install, everything works perfectly. It happens only when i start the app after my device has been locked for a while

Comment: You might be in the middle of a connection retry backoff period.  Check the log to see what it's doing and if it might be trying to reconnect periodically.

Comment: It might have something to do with the SHA1 fingerprint. I did not enter this key when creating the project in firebase. I created a new project with an SHA1 key, and everything seems to be working fine for now

Comment: @PrisonMike I am also facing same issue in recent  releases  is your problem solvedafter adding SHA1

Comment: this was a long time ago but yes i think it was solved by that